# Getting a javascript $(function() function to trigger

Tags: javascript

I don't know js very well, only use it when I have to, using routines stolen from the web.

I have some radio buttons and three chained (cascading) SELECT inputs that need to interact.
I've found a robust code library (jCombo) for the chained SELECTS that works well and I'm trying to add some radio buttons to the mix (the selected radio button value is also passed to the AJAX routines the populate the SELECTS. Everything works if I change the selected radio button and refresh the page. Now I just need the chained SELECTS to dynamically auto-populate when the radio button change (without having to refresh the page).

```
<form method=get action="" id="fred">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<input type="radio" name="degree" class="degree" value="C" form="fred">
<input type="radio" name="degree" class="degree" value="A" form="fred">
<input type="radio" name="degree" class="degree" value="B" form="fred" checked >
<input type="radio" name="degree" class="degree" value="M" form="fred">
<input type="radio" name="degree" class="degree" value="P" form="fred">

<select name="cat" id="cat" form="fred"></select><br />
<select name="deg" id="deg" form="fred"></select><br  />
<select name="conc" id="conc" form="fred"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
var degType = $('input[name=degree]:checked').val();
$(function() {
$("#cat").jCombo("getCategories.php?typ="+degType, { selected_value : '1' } );
$("#deg").jCombo("getDegrees.php?typ="+degType+"&cat=", { parent: "#cat" });        
$("#conc").jCombo("getConcentrations.php?typ="+degType+"&deg=", { parent: "#deg" });
});
</script>
```

What can be added to get the jCombo routines to fire when the user clicks a different radio button?

This code is sandboxed [here](http://birchy.com/jCombo/example_test.html)

Comment: why was this voted down?! I spent a lot of time on it, got a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $('.degree').change(function() {
    var degType = $(this).val();
    $("#cat").jCombo("getCategories.php?typ="+degType, { selected_value : '1' } );
    $("#deg").jCombo("getDegrees.php?typ="+degType+"&cat=", { parent: "#cat" });        
    $("#conc").jCombo("getConcentrations.php?typ="+degType+"&deg=", { parent: "#deg" });
  }).change();  // trigger it at first time.
});
```

Comment: Seems to be working, thanks! The SELECT widths jump around, may have to make them fixed width. I also need to add a "wait" flag somehow, as the AJAX routines take quite a while to populate the SELECTS.